# Why my getservbyname function always return NULL?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, null, linux-mint

Right now i'm having some troubles with the `getservbyname()` function in linux mint, every time i try to get a port it returns `NULL` and i don't know what could be

```
   extern struct servent *get_port(char *name, char *prot) {
      struct servent *tmp;
      tmp = getservbyname(name, prot);
      if(tmp == NULL) {
        return NULL;
      }
      return tmp;
    }
```

This is how i call the function

```
    struct servent *port;

    if((port = (struct servent*)get_port("server", "tcp")) == NULL){
        perror("Error... \n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Got the port... \n");
```

I used the perror function to get more information about the problem, but every time i run the code i get that the function worked correctly...

Comment: So the name of the well-known service your looking up is "server" ? interesting. I must look that up in my /etc/services file. Didn't know that existed (thus somewhat flying in the face of "well-known"). Edit: 8000+ entries in my services file, nothing about a service called "server". Is that really the name you're trying to find ?

Answer (score 2):

`getservbyname()` does not set `errno`, so `perror()` does not work.

If it returns `NULL` then the most likely reason is that the service you specified does not exist in the services file, or the services file cannot be opened.

The name in your example `"server"` is not one that would be commonly included in a services database - trying looking up a service like `"ftp"`.

Comment: Also note that, while `getservbyname` should work when passed a correct service name, it's obsoleted by `getaddrinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

From `getservbyname` man page:

> The getservbyname() function returns a servent structure for the entry
>   from the database that  matches  the  service  **name**  using 
>   protocol proto.  If **proto** is NULL, any protocol will be matched.

The `/etc/services` file has the following structure:

```
echo        7/tcp
echo        7/udp
ftp         21/tcp
smtp        25/tcp
```

There are services available either in *tcp* and *udp* protocols (*echo*), while others are only available in one of them (*ftp*, *smtp*). The `getservbyname` function queries the `/etc/services` file searching for a service name and returns a struct containing information such as *name*, *port number*, *protocol* and *aliases*.

The problem with your code, as others already pointed out, is that the ***name*** parameter of the function is not a server name (such as *localhost* or whatever), but the service name you're looking for (*ftp*, for instance). The ***proto*** parameter is optional, when its value is NULL it matches any protocol. Valid protocols are *tcp* or *udp*, in case you're particularly interested in one of them.